# DirectX SDK (June 2010) Installation Problems: Error Code S1023

Tags: directx, vista64

I seem to be having some problems installing the DirectX SDK. Everything seems to be going well during the install, but at the end I get the message:

> Setup failed.
> Errors were encountered during installation of redistributable packages.
> Please close all open programs and try running setup again.
> If problems persist, contact DirectX Developer Support.
>
> Error Code: S1023

Well, I have tried closing all open programs and installing again but I get the same error. What is error code `S1023`? I tried *Googling*, but found many different responses for how to deal with it and I'm not sure what to do.

I have tried looking in the log files in `C:\Windows\Logs`. There are 2 log files, `DirectX.log` and `DirectX_SDK.log`. I do not see any noticeable signs of "error" or "failure" of any kind.

In fact, the very last line in DirectX.log is:

> 11/04/10 18:36:27: dsetup32: Installation ended with value 0 = Installation succeeded

Could anyone please help? I am running Vista (x64).

Comment: i believe in most cases the reason for this error is that you installed a program (for instance a game) which brought the redistributable version up higher than the sdk's redistributable version, causing the install to fail. i'm not sure whether it matters that the install fails or not.

Comment: Not enough rep to answer but since this isn't mentioned anywhere here: make sure to right click and select "run as administrator" on the installer.

Comment: Seems no-one mentioned this, but you can just ignore the message.  SDK is installed, and env vars set (Win10, June 2010 SDK)

Answer (score 283):

I had the same problem and for me it was because the vc2010 redist x86 was too recent.

Check your temp folder (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp) for the most recent file named

### Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable Setup_20110608_xxx.html ##

and check if you have the following error

> Installation Blockers:
>
> A newer version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable has been detected on the machine.
>
> Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x000013EC), "A StopBlock was hit or a System >Requirement was not met." (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:00).

then go to Control Panel>Program & Features and uninstall all the

### Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86/x64 redistributable - 10.0.(number over 30319)

After successful installation of DXSDK, simply run Windows Update and it will update the redistributables back to the latest version.

Comment: Just thought I would post and this was my exact problem, thanks for sharing. The OP really should mark this as the solution!

Comment: Any idea **why** newer redistributables collide with the installation? Can I reinstall them after the setup? Or will they cause trouble?

Comment: If you customize the installation, you can refrain from installing the redistributable. Thus, you can keep the newer one when installing the SDK. Alternatively, you could just uninstall it as suggested and reinstall it after.

Comment: Is there any risks in deleting redistribuables?

Comment: @Fibericon FYI I seem to be unable to deselect the option to install the DX redistribuable. I'll try the other way around. Thanks for suggesting, though!

Comment: What the fork Microsoft? Thanks

Comment: There is a bug in the original VS 2010 RTM REDIST packages when run on a sytem with VS 2010 SP1 or newer packages already installed. The VS 2010 RTM version is included in the DirectX SDK (June 2010). Since the DirectX SDK is end-of-life, there's no future update to the SDK to fix this by updating the VS REDIST Exes. This issue also affects the Windows 7.1 SDK. See KB[2728613](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2728613) and KB[2717426](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426).

Answer (score 88):

I've had the same problem twice already and the easiest and most concise solution that I found is located [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error.aspx) (in MSDN Blogs -> Games for Windows and the DirectX SDK). However, just in case that page goes down, here's the method:

1. Remove the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package version 10.0.40219 (Service Pack 1) from the system (both x86 and x64 if applicable). This can be easily done via a command-line with administrator rights:

   ```
   MsiExec.exe /passive /X{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}
   MsiExec.exe /passive /X{1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}
   ```
2. Install the DirectX SDK (June 2010)
3. Reinstall the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package version 10.0.40219 (Service Pack 1). On an x64 system, you should install both the x86 and x64 versions of the C++ REDIST. Be sure to install the most [current version available](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26999), which at this point is the KB 2565063 with a security fix.

> **Note:** This issue does not affect earlier version of the DirectX SDK which deploy the VS 2005 / VS 2008 CRT REDIST and do not deploy the VS 2010 CRT REDIST. This issue does not affect the DirectX End-User Runtime web or stand-alone installer as those packages do not deploy any version of the VC++ CRT.

**File Checksum Integrity Verifier**: This of course assumes you actually have an uncorrupted copy of the DirectX SDK setup package. The best way to validate this it to run

```
fciv -sha1 DXSDK_Jun10.exe
```

and verify you get

```
8fe98c00fde0f524760bb9021f438bd7d9304a69 dxsdk_jun10.exe
```

Comment: I already have the link to the article in my answer, @midspace

Comment: Thanks Gregory. My browser (IE) must have been giving me grief that day, as I don't remember seeing any links (no colored text) in your post at all. Using Safari today, and I can see all of em. :/

Comment: Just doing number 1 helps me.. Your answer that is, not taking a oui oui

Answer (score 23):

Here is the official answer from Microsoft: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error.aspx

Summary if you'd rather not click through:

1. Remove the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package version 10.0.40219 (Service Pack 1) from the system (both x86 and x64 if applicable). This can be easily done via a command-line with administrator rights:

   MsiExec.exe /passive /X{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}

   MsiExec.exe /passive /X{1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}
2. Install the DirectX SDK (June 2010)
3. Reinstall the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package version 10.0.40219 (Service Pack 1). On an x64 system, you should install both the x86 and x64 versions of the C++ REDIST. Be sure to install the most current version available, which at this point is the KB2565063 with a security fix.

Windows SDK: The Windows SDK 7.1 has exactly the same issue as noted in [KB 2717426](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426).

Comment: This by far was the easiest solutions. I love how you added the Msiexec commands, saved me a lot of hassle. Ended up removing the updated versions, and the install went great. I'll think about re-adding them once I locate the app that required them.

Answer (score 2):

Find Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86/x64 Redistributable – 10.0.xxxxx in the control panel of the add or remove programs 
if xxxxx > 30319
renmove it

I just wanted to say that this(I also emptied my temp folder, in Computer->C:->Properties->Disk Cleanup) made the DirectX June 2010 SDK install without failure, I have Vista32bit for all it matters.
Thank you Mr.Lyn! :)

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling too much on my Win7-64bit machine I was stuck here too.  I didn't want to reinstall the OS and none of the tricks worked expect for this registry hack below.  Most of this trick I found in an old pchelpforum port but I had to adapt it to my 64-bit installation:

(For a 32-bit repair, probably skip the Wow6432Node path)

1. Start regedit
2. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-> SOFTWARE-> Wow6432Node-> Microsoft->DirectX
3. If this DirectX folder doesn't exist, create it.
4. If already here, make sure it's empty.
5. Now right click in the empty window on the right and add this data (there will probably be at least a Default string value located here, just leave it):

   ```
   New->Binary Value
   Name: InstalledVersion
   Type: REG_BINARY
   Data: 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00

   New->DWORD (32-bit) Value
   Name: InstallMDX
   Type: REG_DWORD
   Data: 0x00000001

   New->String Value
   Name: SDKVersion
   Type: REG_SZ
   Data: 9.26.1590.0

   New->String Value
   Name: Version
   Type: REG_SZ
   Data: 4.09.00.0904
   ```
6. Reinstall using latest DXSDK installer.  Runtime only option may work too but I didn't test it.
7. Profit!

Comment: The solution on Microsoft site: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-code-s1023-when-trying-to-install-directx/0aadf7ec-e004-42eb-8a1a-2865ff5b3a37

Answer (score 1):

Find Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86/x64 Redistributable – 10.0.xxxxx in the control panel of the add or remove programs 
if xxxxx > 30319
renmove it

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this issue too. And I'm running in XP SP3.

The following website http://www.docin.com/p-60410380.html#  pointing out the solution.
But it's simplified Chinese.

I translated its main idea into English here.

run regedit;
open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX
Then you must change the following two items:
Item 1:
Name: Version, 
Type:REG_SZ, 
The value should be a rather little number to make the installation success.

Item 2:
Name: SDKVersion. But in your machine, the name can be different, for example, it can be ManagedDirectXVersion. But the type should be REG_SZ.
Type:REG_SZ, 
The value should be a rather little number to make the installation success.

In fact, you can refer to the DirectX.lgo file to find the exact version number.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the already excellent answer by Ugo Robain, I'd just like to point out that the S1023 error could also happen due to:

> Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17. Restart required. The installation or update for the product required a restart for all changes to take effect. The restart was deferred to a later time.

I'm unsure if this is due to TiWorker being too dumb to handle the installation on-the-fly with previous/newer versions already installed, or if perhaps it couldn't have been me with some opened program holding a handle on `msvcr90.dll`.. anyhow even after some tinkering the only way forward here seemed to reboot.