# Can't install DirectX SDK (Jun10) in VirtualBox?

Tags: c++, sdk, directx, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to setup a Windows-VM for C++ development on my Win7.

Currently I am using:

- **Oracle VM VirtualBox** 4.3.20
- **"IE11 on Windows 7"** for VirtualBox on Windows from [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools)

*Note:* Later on I want to use Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013.

Inside my fresh Windows-VM I tried to install **DirectX SDK** (Jun10) and the *expected* S1023 Error occurred. I know there are some solutions - [like this one (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102259/directx-sdk-june-2010-installation-problems-error-code-s1023) or [KB2728613](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2728613) - with uninstalling C++ redistributables or using `regedit` but not a single one succeeded.

In the programs and functions there is no redistributable listed.

Any help, suggestions or alternatives for me?

Comment: The solution is to uninstall all versions of the VS 2010 REDIST, then run the DXSDK (Jun 2010) which will install the VS 2010 RTM version. You then install the latest VS 2010 REDIST. See [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error.aspx) post.

Comment: You don't actually need the DirectX SDK to do C++ development if you are going to use VS 2013. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx).

Comment: And since you installed IE11 for Windows 7, the DXSDK (Jun 2010) has all the same problems on Windows 7 with DirectX 11.1 as it does with Windows 8.x. Ideally, don't use it. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx)

Comment: I want to use Qt5.3 and in the requirements for windows (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-requirements.html) it says "Building the library requires the installation of the Direct X SDK" and in the wiki (http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC) it says "Required SDKs and tools [...] Microsoft DirectX SDK"

Comment: Someone should clean up that library to not require the legacy DirectX SDK... Sounds like a good open source project. Anyhow, if you are going to us VS 2013 with the DirectX SDK, be sure to read the instructions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) about how to mix the include/lib paths correctly.