# Matlab 2014b and mex files, has anyone been able to use Visual Studio Express?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, windows-7-x64, mex

I know that Visual Studio Pro will allow you to compile mex files for MATLAB 2014b.

However I was wondering if anyone was able to use Visual Studio Express (which is free, as opposed to Pro which is not) to compile mex files? I tried the Windows SDK (recommended by mathworks), with no success.

Update: This is the error I get:
A problem occurred while installing selected Windows SDK components. Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm

Only I can't find that file.

Details:

Windows 7

MATLAB 2014b

Things I Did So Far:

SDK 7.1, I tried installing this not sure if it did not install correctly or was not actually a solution (from here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html)

Download the 30 day trial of Visual Studio Pro which is working

Comment: If not necessarily MSVC, have you tried [gnumex](http://gnumex.sourceforge.net/)? I tested it successfully with `R2012b`, but not with `2014b`. Note also, that despite what's their [website](http://de.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html) says, `R2014b` runs still with `MSVC 2005`. This is also what `mex.getCompilerConfigurations('c','Supported')` gives.

Comment: Note: `Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005` can be downloaded for free ( - as I think, did'nt check out myself). It does not support `c99`, just in case that is required.

Comment: @embert Where can I find VS 2005?  I went to the VS 2005 page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950416.aspx) but the Visual Studios 2005 Express Edition link redirected to the 2013 edition (http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs)

Comment: Don't use a 10 year old compiler. Please!  Try again with SDK 7.1 and check for [certain MS bugs that might cause a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19105762/2778484).  See here for supported compilers: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html

Comment: Try [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5553) or [here](http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2005-Standard-Edition/3000-2212_4-194622.html). Of course new compilers are better, I guess. But often something that works is better than something that's better but doesn't work. Ah..actually a have no clue about all those versions, that exist. So..be aware.

Comment: What is the error?  Express editions are not supported anymore.

Comment: mex -setup always says that "No supported SDK or compiler was found"

Comment: Try the MS hotfix from the answer I linked to above.  This seems to be a common issue when certain updates.  Also be sure select any options for 64-bir compilers if MATLAB is 64-bit.  If all else fails, manually verify the SDK install worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I used to use that exact combination if I recall. Make sure you get the right version of it though. Share the actual problem and maybe we can work around it.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer since I can't roll back and reproduce these errors. I got a copy of Visual Studios Pro from my boss and so I will not be going back to Express to test this. I would like to thank you for your help anyway. I might be testing mex files for a few older versions of matlab in coming weeks and if I learn anything useful I will add it just for completeness.   Thanks again, Erin

Answer (score 1):

This is another common issue with the Windows SDK 7.1 where it [won't install if you have a newer Visual Studio 2010 runtime than version 10.0.30319](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426/de), which is what it tries to install (you would think they would update the SDK installer!). You have to remove them before installing the SDK:

```
MsiExec.exe /passive /X{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}
MsiExec.exe /passive /X{1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}
```

Then the SDK will install and you can reinstall [the latest 2010 runtimes](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26999).

There is an identical issue with the old DirectX SDK (June 2010) and [the solution is much the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9401911/2778484).