# D3D9 64-bit debug runtime

Tags: direct3d, direct3d9

For debugging D3D9 applications enabling the DirectX 9 Debug Runtime is essential.

(The [June 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) must be installed first.)

For 64-bit applications it can be enabled in the *DirectX Control Panel (64-bit)* by checking *Use Debug Version of Direct3D 9*.

Problem: It resets back to *Retail* when the control panel is closed, and basically doesn't do anything.

(The 32-bit equivalent works.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102259/directx-sdk-june-2010-installation-problems-error-code-s1023 if installing the SDK fails

Answer (score 5):

[Kjell Andersson found the answer](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/644399-d3d9-64-bit-debug-runtime/):

> The problem originates from a Windows 7 update that locked down the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D` registry key to a user named `TrustedInstaller`. This made the Administrator not having rights to update the settings in the registry key - thus not allowing us to switch to a debug version of Direct3D 9.
>
> To fix this problem you have to follow this procedure:
>
> 1. Using regedit as an Administrator, go to the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D` key.
> 2. Select *Permissions...* from the context menu on the key.
> 3. Press the *Advanced* button.
> 4. Go to the *Owner* tab and select the *Administrator* as the owner. *Apply* the changes and close the *Advanced* settings.
> 5. Back in the *Premissions* dialog select the *Administrators* group and check *Full Control*. *Apply* changes and close dialog.
>
> You are now able to start the *DirectX Control Panel* from the *DirectX SDK June 2010* and switch to the debug runtime.

Comment: Keep in mind that Direct3D 9 debugging basically only works on Windows 7 or earlier. The only way to get debug support for Direct3D 9 with Windows 8.x or Windows 10 is to install a 'checked' build of the OS.